# Is nesting lambda expressions in c# bad practice?

Tags: c#, lambda, nested

I work a lot with the windows phone and I noticed it is a challenge at times when you are working with multiple systems that return at different speeds and all exicute async.

One of the ways I came up with for dealing with this (that works amazingly) is nesting lambdas. It controls the flow of exicution and prevents race events while also not locking the UI up. My question is though is I kinda just through this together without much research.

Is nesting multiple lambdas bad practice? What are some of the negitive implications?

Assume the following

### Its not real code, I watered it down so it could be understood easily, relax

```
Query.AsyncExicute();

CheckQueryCompletedBagTimer.Tick += (sender1,arg1) =>{
    
      if(bag.count<=0)
          return;
      else{
         MakeAnotherQuery.Exicute();
         CheckQueryCompletedBagTimer2.Tick += (sender2,arg2) =>{
            //Do some more code

          };

      }
};

CheckQueryCompletedBagTimer.Start();
```

Comment: Did you mean to subscribe same timer event twice. In a lambda and a nested lambda?

Comment: nesting events may be but I wouldn't say lambdas is - Prime example is `list.Where(x => otherList.Any(y => x == y))`

Comment: No I fixed it. Why the down votes. Isn't this a valid question?

Comment: Is the TPL unavailable on Windows Phone?  This seems like a reinvention of continuations (wouldn't you rather see `ContinueWith()`?)

Comment: What is TPL? @48klocs

Comment: [TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) stands for Task Paralell Library

Comment: @AMR TPL is the Task Parallel Library.  If you have methods expressed as tasks, it allows you to chain calls together in a more readable way.

Comment: Oh is that similar to using async and await?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that if nesting lambdas does not affect the performance there should be no problem about using them.

But if there is a more straight way of achieving the same results without nesting use it, since nesting lambdas can affect understading and maintainabilityof code.

A `//comment` above the nested lambda expresion explaining clearly what you are doing is a must (for me)